# Inequality about exponential integrals

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

I am reading about Dirichlet polynomials in the book Analytic Number Theory by Iwaniec-Kowalski.
During the proof of Theorem 9.1 for any positive real numbers $T, N$ they define a piecewise linear and continuous function $f(t)$ which is an upper bound for the indicator function of     $[0,T]$ and vanishes whenever $t>T+N$ or $t<-N$. Then they use the following bound without comment,
$$
x > 1 
\Rightarrow
\left|
\int_{t \in \mathbb R}f(t) x^{it }\mathrm d t \right|
=O\left( \frac{1}{N (\log x )^2} \right)
.$$

Can anyone justify this inequality?

Comment: Integrate by parts twice, to get $(i \log x)^{-2} \int_{\mathbb R} f''(t) x^{it} dt$.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask what happens with $f''(t)$ when $t$ is near the points of discontinuouity?

Comment: OK, that was a little bit too fast; but the idea is the same: integrate by parts twice on each interval $(t_{j-1}, t_j)$ where $f$ is linear. The terms with $(i \log x)^{-1} f(t_j) x^{i t_j}$ cancel out, the terms $(i \log x)^{-2} f'(t_j) x^{i t_j}$ are $O(N^{-1} (\log x)^{-2})$, and what remains is an integral involving $f'' = 0$.

Comment: Great, it works! How could you have predicted that the terms would cancel out without looks at the specific formulas? Edit: i guess this only has to do with the fact that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, this is just the matter of continuity. The above calculation is the usual trick for the Fourier transform, re-written in terms of the Mellin transform.

Comment: "the said authors"???